# Symfony "Type" constraint: Expected argument of type "string", "array" given exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form. For example, it's login form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('phone', TextType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new Type(['type' => 'string']),
            new Length(['max' => 255]),
            new ValueExistsInEntity([
                'entityClass' => User::class,
                'field' => 'phone',
                'message' => 'User not found'
            ])
        ]
    ]);
    $builder->add('password', TextType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new Type(['type' => 'string']),
            new Length(['min' => 8, 'max' => 128])
        ]
    ]);
}
```

As you can see, it has `Length` constraint. When I send an array to any field in my form, `Length` constraint throws `Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Exception\\UnexpectedTypeException` and 500 status code with message:

> Expected argument of type "string", "array" given

Is there any way to avoid this or convert this exception to form validation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I've found was to create event listener which simply converts exception to beauty error (it's okay for me because I'm developing API only, not full stack).

Simplified part of my exception event listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Exceptions\FormValidationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ValidatorException;

class ApiExceptionListener
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $isKernelDebug;

    public function __construct(bool $isKernelDebug)
    {
        $this->isKernelDebug = $isKernelDebug;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $throwedException = $event->getException();

        $errorBody = [
            'code'    => $throwedException->getCode(),
            'message' => $throwedException->getMessage(),
        ];

        if ($throwedException instanceof ValidatorException) {
            $errorBody['message'] = 'Invalid data has been sent';
        }

        if ($this->isKernelDebug) {
            $errorBody['exception'] = [
                'class'   => get_class($throwedException),
                'message' => $throwedException->getMessage(),
                'code'    => $throwedException->getCode(),
            ];
        }

        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse(['error' => $errorBody]));
    }
}
```

Service:

```
app.event_listener.api_exception:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ApiExceptionListener
    arguments: ['%%kernel.debug%%']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException, priority: 200 }
```

But I'll glad to see better solutions for handling exceptions thrown from Symfony constraints.

Answer (score -1):

Because `Length` is validator for strings only. For arrays you have to use `Count` validator.

If you want to use both arrays and strings in the same validator, you should implement your own [Custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Comment: I don't need to validate arrays. As you can see, I have `new Type(['type' => 'string'])` on both fields. Array is invalid input data for my fields. But Symfony validation throws 500 error when I send an array from my form instead of string.

Comment: But all the validator will be called. So, in your case Type validator will fail, but Length validator however will be applied to the same dataset. Because Lenght validator expects strings instead array, it throws exception. Nothing wrong with behavior.